# How can I assign an element to have a scaling transformation in percentage relative to the window in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, transform, scaling

For example, I can achieve the same thing by applying the formula:

```js
const { width } = useWindowDimension();
const porcentage = width * 0.8 (80% of the window);

<ComponentOrElement style={ width: porcentage } />
```

But this is based on the `width` (or also the `height`) of the element, I want to obtain the same but based on the scaling transformation. For example:

```js
const { width } = useWindowDimension();
const porcentage = width * 0.8 (80% of the window?);

<ComponentOrElement style={ transform: [ { scale: porcentage } ] } />
```

Scaling has a range of `0` to `1` (or more, but it always refers to a factor, not pixels, dp, etc.).

How can I achieve this in scaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will scale and keep the view in centre:

```
const { width } = useWindowDimension();    

<ComponentOrElement style={{ width: width, transform: [{ scaleX: 0.8 }] }} />
```

Shift to right:

```
const scale = .8;

<ComponentOrElement
  style={{
    width: width,
    transform: [{ translateX: width * (1 - scale) * 0.5 }, { scaleX: scale }],
  }}
/>
```

Shift to left:

```
<ComponentOrElement
  style={{
    width: width,
    transform: [{ translateX: width * (scale - 1) * 0.5 }, { scaleX: scale }],
  }}
/>
```

But they will distort the content